# Bootstrap big margin above h1 heading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.row {background-color: pink;}
h1 {background-color: cyan;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
 <div class='row'>
  <h1>China</h1>
 </div>
</div><!--end container-->
```

There is a big margin at the top of the `h1` tag. When I use the inspect tool in the browser to disable the margin of the `h1` it only gets bigger. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I use the inspect tool in the browser to disable the margin of the h1 it only gets bigger. Why is this?

In the screenshot, do you see where it says `h1` and `bootstrap.css:62` in the third box from the bottom?

When you disabled the margins on the `h1` located at `bootstrap.css:1224`, the other one was applied. `margin: .67em 0` applies a top and bottom margin based on the `font-size`, which is fairly large, so that explains why the margin becomes larger when you disable the other one.

Comment: There are also browser defaults. Try explicitly setting `margin: 0;` on `h1` to remove the default margin.

Comment: Well you are right. I would have thought that browser defaults would show up in the inspector but they don't I guess. I also thought bootstrap had a css reset of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

You need to set margin of `h1 {margin: 10px 10px!important;}` to fix issue.

```css
.row {background-color: pink;}
h1 {background-color: cyan; margin: 10px 10px!important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
 <div class='row'>
  <h1>China</h1>
 </div>
</div><!--end container-->
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why removing it in the inspector has no effect?

Comment: You want to remove complete margin from top and bottom?

Comment: I'm just curious as to why removing it in the inspector had no effect first.